# Searching a word to describe a person who has a lot of influence over a group or society

Tags: phrase-requests

for example a famous person has a lot of influence over the society.

they are like axis or sth in the society.

Comment: "Influential person" find it in google translate? sounds weird to me!

Comment: what has your research yielded?

Comment: no research in ? nor 2 answers. One answer even has 2 upvotes ... i  depart my interest in this question.

Answer (score 2):

You do hear the term [**thought leader**](https://www.forbes.com/sites/russprince/2012/03/16/what-is-a-thought-leader/#375574497da0) to describe such a person, although it may not have reached the dictionary yet. (-:

Answer (score 1):

"Influential person" or "influential figure" works. There isn't really an individual formal word I can think of, but there are some slang terms, such as "big cheese".